# Should I use Anaconda on Ubuntu WSL for other reasons than datascience?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda

I've been away from Python for a while (just a normal guy trying to learn it) and wanted to start learning again. I came across Anaconda and I am trying to figure out whether to use it or stick to pip. There are several questions for this, but they are all related to people using Python for Datascience, which I use R for.

So, is there any reason for me to use Anaconda if I am not planning on working with Datascience?

Sorry if this question seems easy to answer by searching, but I cannot find any information about this that isn't related to Datascience.

Answer (score -1):

Off-hand, I'd say no. Anaconda simply clumps many (not all) of the standard data science-y packages with Python. If you go base Python, you get a much smaller install. Now one thing that is useful: conda. I find it's pretty good at managing package versions, which can be pretty problematic otherwise. But you can probably get by without it.